# One try/catch for each error, or one global try catch and switch error?

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, clean-code

I have multiple methods that could fail, let's say :

1. readFile()
2. parseFile()
3. compute()

Each of them could fail (e.g file not found, wrong file type, wrong data), should I put each of them in their own `try/catch` block or should I create one `try/catch` block then `switch` the error and log/display text depending on the error?

e.g:

```
try {
    readfile()
}
catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw 'Could not read file';
}

try {
    parsefile()
}
catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw 'File corrupted or wrong type';
}

try {
    compute()
}
catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw 'Data is wrong';
}
```

or :

```
try {
    readfile()
    parsefile()
    compute()
}
catch (err) {
    switch(err) {
        case 'NOENT': throw...
        case 'CORRUPTED': throw...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I am a believer that the best reason to catch an exception is to be able to log and then ***recover so as to continue running the program***, for example, informing the user of the failure so they can take an alternate action.

What you're discussing here is alternative constructs/patterns for catching that all re-throw.

*This implies that you necessarily have another try/catch higher up in the call chain that is doing this recovery.*

This higher in the call-stack try/catch can do the logging, which makes the local try/catch (close to the point of throw, where corrective action cannot be taken) seem redundant to me, and I would seek to eliminate these seemingly unnecessary constructs.

```
try {
    parsefile()
}
catch (err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw 'File corrupted or wrong type';
}
```

For example, the above try/catch could be removed by (1) relying on the outer try/catch to log the error and recover the program, and (2) throwing the proper exception in `parsefile()` in the first place.

(It could also be the case that the the `parsefile()` is already throwing a more useful and specific exception that is then being obscured by re-throwing a different more general exception.  Let's recall that exceptions in most languages can participate in hierarchy to simplify some issues here.)

(Of course, there are times when this is impractical, but the question is posed rather generally, so this is a general answer)

Comment: There is a parent component catching all the errors and displaying it to the final user (in this case it's an API) - thus the ``throw`` in my ``catch``. The logging is mostly for debugging in case of errors, if I remove the ``try catch`` here, it just breaks the program and stops instead of keep going (asynchronous code in JS) since the code is in a separate module.

Answer (score 3):

In most situations, I would say "neither". Instead, you should probably go with one `try` followed by multiple `catch` parts.

```
try {
    readFile();
    parseFile();
    compute();
} catch (ReadFileException err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw new SomeException("Cannot read file", err);
} catch (ParseFileException err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw new SomeException("Cannot parse file", err);
} catch (ComputeException err) {
    log.error(err);
    throw new SomeException("Cannot compute results of file", err);
}
```

This keeps your "happy flow" code bundled together, while making it easy to handle different cases.
Your second option has these same advantages, but seems to match on some error message, which is rather brittle. Using different exception types gives your IDE the option to help you.

One note: If there is actually a lot of stuff going on between `readFile()`, `parseFile()` and `compute()`, I would go with 3 `try..catch` blocks instead - what "a lot of stuff" means in that case is very much a matter of personal taste, I think, and something you need to get a feel for.

Comment: The second option is also viable if OP doesn't really care or need to know the specific error that occurred.

Comment: One question arises: why do you think a SomeException is more useful to your caller than e.g. a ReadFileException?

Comment: For Java and similar, this makes perfect sense. However this would not apply to, say, Javascript at all.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Because the fact that there are files and parsing and computing isn't something the caller should know about, the caller just wants to know the end result. To me letting such exceptions bubble up feels like making things more complicated for the caller, without adding actual value.

Comment: @JoryGeerts "The caller wants to know the end result": yes, exactly, and to me that means, he won't care about the type of exception, just the fact that he got some exception, be it a SomeException, a ReadFileException, an IOException, a NullPointerException or whatever - they all mean the same to him. That's why I'd stay with the original one (unless forced to change because of some method signature e.g. in Java).

Comment: I tend to agree with Ralf here though I like that you're answer is at least reducing the number of seemingly superflous `try` blocks. Ideally in my mind, both `try` and `catch` are reduced to a minimum in favor of catching as generally as possible and creating no more "transactions" (if we consider a `try` as modeling one) than needed. There might be cases where it's needed to get more nuanced... perhaps it is useful in some very detailed error handling context for the user to know that an out of memory exception occurred in the parsing aspect of file loading as opposed to reading, e.g...

Comment: ... but unless that level of nuance is required in exceptional paths of execution, often I think it's a lot simpler to just utilize the message inside the exception object itself (without having to know its concrete type so specifically) and try to keep both those `try` and `catch` blocks to a minimum in a way that maps conceptually to ideas like transactions and error recovery sites. That's somehow controversial in certain languages but I don't see why unless this level of nuance and granularity/specificity to the exception handling is actually a practical requirement.

Comment: It might be due to different fields/concerns. For me it's pretty nice already if a codebase can gracefully recover from all possible exceptions that can occur without throwing out of the entry point of a thread and display some stack dump or something. I'm pretty happy just to see like a "Failed to load file '{filename}': {show message attached to exception}" If the error handling gets a lot more contextual and nuanced than that, that's going above and beyond to me and maybe it is a practical requirement in some cases. That tends to call for translating/rethrowing exceptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with Erik's point of view, and I'd like to add some more reasoning to support our recommendation:

```
    readFile();
    parseFile();
    compute();
```

without any try/catch.

What is an exception?

- It signals to your caller that your method did not succeed (fulfill its contract) for whatever reason.
- It contains a description of that failure, typically by using a specific exception class, containing a message and saving the stack trace where the exception happened.
- It abruptly aborts the current control flow in the current and all parent method executions, up to a point where you placed a matching try/catch.

This concept of exception has been thoughtfully designed to give you a well-behaving error handling nearly for free.

In your sample code, you want to catch exceptions and re-throw different ones. Why? What do you think your caller will do based on the exception? And how will your translated exceptions make that job easier?

I have to disappoint you: typically your caller isn't interested at all in the reason of the failure. If your caller gets an exception, he'll just abort himself and tell his caller about that fact (typically by just letting the uncaught exception ripple through). So, replacing the exception with a different one is a waste of time in 99% of cases. I've rarely ever seen code where a method took different branches depending on the type of exception it got.

Somewhere up in the call stack, there's a place where some developer decided to put a try/catch, because he thinks he can continue here. But he'll typically not care about the type of exception. Maybe, he'll retry the call, or just show a message to the user and wait for his next action. And all this works with any type of exception, so there's again no reason to translate exceptions.

One thing you should care about is logging. Make sure you log each exception once, and only once. The sysadmins running your software will hate you if you clutter the logfiles with endless repetitions of the same problem, especially if you re-word it at every catch/re-throw level. So, don't log in places where you re-throw the exception. Error logging belongs in places where exceptions are caught for good.

Make sure every exception carries a useful message. Typically all the exceptions coming from mature libraries will typically have a useful message, but there might be cases where you want to add information (e.g. about context like an object ID), and that's a valid reason for a catch/re-throw. Don't log here, but create and throw a new exception containing the extra info and referring to the original exception, if your language supports that (e.g. Java does). So the log eintry has all the original exception information, typically including the stack trace, being the most important debugging aid available in a production setting.

To sum it up with The Golden Rule of Exception Handling:

- You Shouldn't Catch an Exception Here.
- You Really Shouldn't Catch an Exception Here.
- If Despite of The Rule You Catch an Exception Here, Be Sure You Know a Good Reason Why!